# Adding both image and title to a navigation backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, custom-view, backbarbuttonitem

I'm trying to add an icon (and keep the title) to the back button of my navigation controller. It seems if I set the image of the UIBarButtonItem it hides the title, so I thought I'd try a custom view. I've tried

```
UIButton* customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 32)];

UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

but Apple docs say that the backBarButtonItem ignores custom views, so this doesn't work.

I also tried this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

but the leftBarButtonItem shows up one screen too soon and the hidesBackButton doesn't seem to hide the backBarButtonItem.

Is there another way to get both an image and title onto a navigation backBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 1):

Very first hide the back button provided by `UINavigationController` by susing the code `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`

And set own button with image and title with the following code

```
UIButton* customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 32)];

UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: > iOS7: "When configuring your bar button item, do not assign a custom view to it; the navigation item ignores custom views in the back bar button anyway"

Comment: then how can i add my own image as back button ? @SoftDesigner

Comment: I used this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/20283490/649379 @Vinodh. Also I'll try hiding back button: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21225089/649379