# iOS 7 change backbarbuttonitem text

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, backbarbuttonitem

I would like to remove the backbutton text on iOS 7 so that it is empty and I only have the arrow.
Any suggestions someone?

Comment: Please read the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) of stackoverflow, because your question is missing an important bit: What have you tried and code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870128/ios-7-navigation-bar-custom-back-button-without-title check this question