# iOS 7 UINavigationBar show default back button without title

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UINavigationController` with `rootViewController` as my custom `SearchViewController` and inside that I'm pushing a `detailViewController`.

When I push `detailViewController` the back button shows a back arrow and the title of the previous `viewController`.

I want the title to be hidden and only the back arrow should be shown.

Whenever I set `self.title = @"";` before pushing, it works but when come back I have to reset the title back in `viewWillAppear`. But this is creating some other problems and causing inconsistancy because the title of the first view controller is not constant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should set back button item title on rootViewController.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870128/ios-7-navigation-bar-custom-back-button-without-title

Answer (score 1):

if you want display only back arrow, then select navigation bar of view controller which are link  to another, select attributes inspector, then select "Back Button", enter blank space in text box.

This is work for me.