# Back button on navigation bar

Tags: ios, navigationbar, uibuttonbaritem

How do I achieve this kind of button? Can I do using navigation bar ?

[image]

Comment: If settings is parent view title, by default it will show like this when using UINavigationBarController. If you need to customize, check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870128/ios-7-navigation-bar-custom-back-button-without-title

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `UINavigationController`. Each time you push a new view controller using:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

the new controller gets a back button with the previous controller in the stack name.

Comment: I want to add it to a view not view controller

Comment: I do  not see a reason why not using view controllers with navigation controller in order to push views with back functionality but if you want to put it in a uiview you have to implement a custom UIButton and make it look like the default back button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by giving navigation title in you setting view controller.

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can achieve this by navigationBar. it is very easy in implement by UINavigationBar.

Objective C

// Set this in every view controller so that the back button displays back instead of the root view controller name

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Swift

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```