# ios hide text of left navigation button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I need to show only arrow button and hide text of left navigation button. According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870128/ios-7-navigation-bar-custom-back-button-without-title?lq=1), I can do like this. But if I do like that, slide to go back feature will be destroyed.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

So, I use like this to hide text.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

So far, it is okay. However, if my previous view's searchDisplayController is active and push to new view,it show  left navigation button text. May I know how to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy and paste this line in every view controller:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = " "
```

**Alternatively** you can achieve this in storyboard/xib files using the following steps:-

1. Drag and drop a **Navigation Item** from object library onto your ViewController. Then select the ViewController.
2. Select that **Navigation Item** in the menu on left side(it will the one with back arrow and **Title** as text: "< Title").
3. Select **Attribute Inspector** on the right hand side and replace text: **Title** with an **empty space**.

Repeat these steps for all the the view controllers.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

One solution you will have to add `custom button` for your requirement like this:

```
//create image instance add here back image
UIImage *imgBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image name here"];

//create UIButton instance for UIBarButtonItem
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnBack setImage:imgBack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgBack.size.width,imgBack.size.height);
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//create UIBarButtonItem instance
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnBackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
//set in UINavigationItem
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtnBackItem;
```

Button method given below:

```
-(void)btnBackAction:(id)sender
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT** : For `slide` `swipe` add in `viewDidLoad` method

```
//for enabling swipe gesture
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: I can't do that method because it destroy slide/swipe to go back feature (introduced in ios 7).

Answer (score 2):

**@Atif's** answer is correct. I just want to add in that, instead of copying and pasting the code in all files, create a custom **UINavigationController** and implement the required code as mentioned by **@Atif**.(I cannot comment due to low rating.)