# How to hide only the back bar button item title in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, navigation, back-button

I know to hide the back bar button item. But I want to hide only the title of the bar button i.e. the back button is like this: "< Back". I want only the arrow not the name i.e. "<". How do I remove the "Back" and retain only the back arrow.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870128/ios-7-navigation-bar-custom-back-button-without-title

Answer (score 3):

You can achieved this easily from storyboard, go to your specific view of storyboard for whom you want to show blank back button title with arrow.

**Then make sure you added navigation item in your specific view:**

[image]

**Then on the right panel you can find:**

[image]

**You just need to give some empty space in the back button box:**

[image]

And you are done.
Hope it will help you thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you....

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: For some reason this code doesn't work for me. The back bar button item still doesn't show when I use this code.

Answer (score 1):

It's Easy

(1) Create LeftbarButton item

```
UIImage *imgBackArrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow"];
UIBarButtonItem *barBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:imgBackArrow style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackButton;
```

(2) Hide Xcode back Button

`[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing the delegate method of UINavigationController.

`func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, 
  willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, 
                    action: nil)
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
    }`

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 3.1**
You can do this by implementing the delegate method of UINavigationController. It'll hide the Title with back button only, we'll still get the back arrow image and default functionality.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, 
  willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let barBttn = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, 
                    action: nil)
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBttn
    }
```