# How to remove the back arrow ios 7 navigation bar?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

In my custom navigation bar, i want to use hide default back button and use my customize left button, but even if the back button is hidden, it sill take some space at the left end of navigation bar.

[image]

How to get rid of back arrow button completely?
I have tried to set `backBarButtonItem` and 'hidesBackButton`properties of`UINavigationItem`, but none of these works.

UPDATED:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
//...
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_backButtonView];
//...
}
```

I use Spark Inspector to inspect the view hierarchy.

[image]

As you see, the back arrow button still takes some space in navigation bar.

UPDATED:

The back arrow is actually an instance of _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView, it look like  a private class.

[image]

UPDATED:

It turns out the problem have nothing to do with the `UINavigationbarBackIndicatorView`. iOS 7 will add spacing before the left item.

this problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897470/ios7-excessive-navigationbar-button-padding). Found the answer.

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `hidesBackButton` to YES before you push the controller. That is the navigation controller should be set hidebackbutton in previous viewcontroller if the pushing view must have hidden back button.

I hope this may help you.

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work. And it happen even with my first view controller in navigation stack.

Comment: I meant i have a leftbutton item for root view controller, but in the navigation bar, the hidden back arrow still take space the and make the leftbutton item shift a bit the the right.

Comment: In root view controller its not possible for back button in navigation controller. Its not hideBackButton problem I think. If you are using the navigation bar image then can you please check whether that image contains the back arrow. If not then its some other problem for it. check for the logic you have done before u load the navigation root viewcontroller

Comment: check my update, i did set bg for navigation bar image, but the arrow is instance of UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView. And if the back arrow is part of the bg image, it will NOT take space like that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897470/ios7-excessive-navigationbar-button-padding)

The solution from that question work for me.